# Excel VBA Function to Trim Right of String (Repeatedly)

Tags: excel, vba, function, return

So, this should NOT be this hard, but clearly, my time away from VBA has dulled my skills.

The function is supposed to take two arguments, a string (s) and a suffix (x) to remove (until it isn't used as a suffix in s anymore...).

```
Function RightRemoveRecursive(ByVal s As String, ByVal x As String) As String
    Dim t As String
    t = s
    Do While (Mid(t, Len(t) - Len(x) + 1, Len(x)) = x)
        t = Mid(t, 1, Len(t) - Len(x))
    Loop
    RightRemoveRecursive = t
End Function
```

In the VBA debugger, I see the value of "t" morph into ***what I want*** returned. However, when the Do While ... Loop is complete (While test fails), the code never executes the function return value (name) line of code... Setting a breakpoint on the assignment to the Function name never "breaks" on that line... Example: s = "01.00.00.00.00.00.00" and x = ".00" ... t should be "01"

I'm baffled.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Len(t) - Len(x) + 1` is returning a `0` to the first criterion on mid.  It does not like that.  Instead use `Application.Max` to return 1 if the value is ever lower:

```
Function RightRemoveRecursive(ByVal s As String, ByVal x As String) As String
    Dim t As String
    t = s
    Do While (Mid(t, Application.Max(Len(t) - Len(x) + 1, 1), Len(x)) = x)
        t = Mid(t, 1, Len(t) - Len(x))
    Loop
    RightRemoveRecursive = t
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Well, how embarrassing! But I am grateful. Thanks, Scott Craner.

Comment: As late addition to your valid & helpful answer solving OP's issue, I posted a late alternative via tricky tokenizing you might be interested in +:)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of the art a late alternative to Scott's valid answer demonstrating tokenizing of a string input:

```
Function RightRepl(ByVal s As String, srch As String)
'a) split into tokens (preserving possible blanks)
    Dim tokens: tokens = Split(Replace(s, " ", "|"), srch)
'b) join tokens trimming right hand blanks
    s = Trim(Join(tokens))
'c) restore original blanks (as well as possible intermediate srch elements)
    RightRepl = Replace(Replace(s, " ", srch), "|", " ")
End Function
```

**Note** *that the function preserves original blanks (as well as possible intermediate ".00" elements) before trim joining.*

**Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim s    As String: s = "01.00.00.00.00.00.00.00"
    Dim srch As String: srch = ".00"
    Debug.Print vbTab & s & vbNewLine & _
       "==> " & vbTab & RightRepl(s, srch)   ' << helper function
End Sub
```

**Result in VB Editor's immediate window**

```
    01.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
==> 01
```